# Get entire Playwright page in html and Text

Tags: javascript, node.js, playwright

I am using playwright in nodejs and I am having some problems when getting the page Text or Html. I just want to get the url as string like: `<html><div class="123"><a>link</a>something</div><div>somethingelse</div></hmtl>`

```
const browser = await playwright.chromium.launch({
    headless: true,
});

const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto(url);
```

I was trying to use `const pageText = page.$('div').innerText;` and also `const pageText2 = await page.$$eval('div', el => el.innerText);`
But both do not work and just give me undefined.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For the full html of the page, this is what you need: `const html = await page.content()`

To get the inner text of the div, this should work: `const pageText = await page.innerText('div')`

See:

- https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-content
- https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-inner-text